# Separate multiple columns and name column names after part of string R

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, dplyr, delimiter

I've got data which saved all the survey question responses to the same cell. I'm trying to find a way to split the data into multiple columns and use the part of each string until a set delimiter as the column name.
The table looks like this at the moment

| ID | Response |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "gender":"Female","occupation":"student","handed":"Left" |
| 2 | "gender":"Female","occupation":"Reporter","handed":"Right" |

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Response = c("\"gender\":\"Female\",\"occupation\":\"student\",\"handed\":\"Left\"", 
"\"gender\":\"Female\",\"occupation\":\"Reporter\",\"handed\":\"Right\""
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

and I would like it to look like this

| ID | gender | occupation | handed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Female" | "student" | "Left" |
| 2 | "Female" | "Reporter" | "Right" |

I've managed to separate the question and response into one column with this

```
df<- df%>%
  mutate(NUM = row_number()) #row number is used as a key for merge

dfdelimted<- 
  str_split_fixed(df$response, ',"', 50)

dfdelimted<-data.frame(dfdelimted)
dfdelimted<- dfdelimted%>%
  mutate(NUM = row_number()) #row number is used as a key for merge

df <-  merge(df,dfdelimted, by="NUM")
```

Which outputs this:

| ID | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "gender":"Female" | "occupation":"student" | "handed":"Left" |
| 2 | "gender":"Female" | "occupation":"Reporter" | "handed":"Right" |

I can't seem to figure out how to word this for a google search so any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with `separate_longer_delim()`. Basically what we're doing is:

1. splitting the Response column on commas, turning each element into it's own row
2. splitting the Reponse column on a ':', into name and the value columns
3. turning it back into wide format, with the column names coming from the name column, and the values from the value column.

```
library("tidyverse")

df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(Response, delim = ",") |>
  separate_wider_regex(Response, patterns = c("\"", "name" = ".*?", "\":\"","value" = ".*?", "\"")) |>
  pivot_wider()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     ID gender occupation handed
  <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr> 
1     1 Female student    Left  
2     2 Female Reporter   Right
```

Maybe there's a way of creating the columns directly. Of course, you could extract them with regex, but I didn't want to presume that the values in the Response column will never change, but if are constant, then that would be the more straightforward approach.

Comment: Thank you! 
I needed to add too_few= and too_many= to the second separate and a select() row before the final pivot, as it then made a row for every response. But otherwise worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df %>%
    mutate(x = list(read.table(text = unlist(strsplit(Response, ",")), sep = ":")), .by = ID) %>%
    unnest(x) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = V1, values_from = V2)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     ID gender occupation handed
  <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
1     1 Female student    Left
2     2 Female Reporter   Right
```

Comment: if you add `id_cols = ID` to pivot_wider, you can omit `select(-Response)` :-)

Comment: @Mark Aha, magic! Sorry that I am newbie of `tidyverse`, but lucky to learn from you :)

Comment: > noobie of tidyverse  >literally has gold badge in dplyr

Comment: you are a pro Thomas, don't lie :-P

Comment: @Mark I usually would like to solve problem with base R, since that forces me to look into the mechanism of solution. `dplyr` badge is obtained by accident :P

Comment: I probably should have said that my separator is two characters ", (it's annoying I know), so I keep getting yelled at since sep = here needs to only be one.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
## create two functions

## extract the json from yout data.frame
extractJson <- function(row) {
  jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0('{', row, '}'))
}

## convert the resulting list to a new data.frame
extractData <- function(list, row) {
  
  list[[row]] %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as.data.frame() -> df
  
  return(df)
  
}

## run functions
purrr::map(df$response, extractJson) -> bd2
do.call(bind_rows, purrr::map(c(1:(bd2 %>% length)), extractData, list = bd2)) -> result

## Get the id column
result %>% 
  mutate(id = df$id) %>% 
  relocate(id, .before = 'gender') -> result
```

The result will be like:

```
  id gender occupation handed
1  1 Female    student   Left
2  2 Female   reporter  Right
```

It's not the best solutions but it works!

Comment: this is quite cool! I like this idea but it doesn't work with the dataset I have

Comment: so sorry! there's some error message?

Comment: I get the old one : `Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {gender:Female,occupation:studen
                     (right here) ------^`

Comment: OH I think I know what happened now

Comment: read.table, when importing it, removed all of the quote marks from the dataframe, probably because I didn't escape them

Comment: but it work now?

Comment: it does! Apologies for the late reply, I was just fixing my own :P

Comment: fyi : you can replace all of the code with just the line `purrr::map_df(df$Response, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0('{', .x, '}')), .id = 'row')`

Comment: this assumes that the ids go from 1 to n, where n is the number of rows. If that's not the case, you'd have to cbind it or something

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

df <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1L, 2L),
    Response = c(
      "gender:Female,occupation:student,handed:Left",
      "gender:Female,occupation:Reporter,handed:Right"
    )
  )

setDT(df)[, list(Response = tstrsplit(Response, split = ",")), by = ID] %>% 
  .[, c("occupation", "handed") := tstrsplit(Response, split = ":", fixed = TRUE)] %>% 
  dcast(formula = ID ~ occupation, value.var = "handed")
#>    ID gender handed occupation
#> 1:  1 Female   Left    student
#> 2:  2 Female  Right   Reporter
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>